# How can I change the background color of the full header in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using the Header component of react-native-elements, which has a blue background by default. I changed it into green, but the upper piece of the header (with the information of your phone, like hour and wifi) stays in blue.

[Header in two colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdbSE.png)

Can someone explain me how to modify this part of the header so all of it would be in light green please ?

Here is my App() code :

```js
export default function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Connexion"
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Connexion" component={ConnexionScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

And this is my page code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Header } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function ConnexionScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Header
        containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#B5F7D3' }}
        leftComponent={{
          icon: 'menu',
          color: '#fff',
          iconStyle: { color: '#fff' },
        }}
        centerComponent={{ text: 'NURISENS', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
        rightComponent={{ icon: 'home', color: '#fff' }}
        barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
        }}>
        <Text>Connexion Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Valider la connexion"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Adding backgroundColor directly in the Header component works perfectly, thanks to both of you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your `StatusBar`. Try to add back `backgroundColor: "#B5F7D3"` prop to your `Header` component.

If the statusBar's color does not change then add the `StatusBar` Component like so:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'
```

and in the `return` statement do implement it like this before the `Header` component.

```js
<StatusBar barStyle = "light-content" hidden = {false} backgroundColor = "#B5F7D3" translucent = {true}/>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`<Header  backgroundColor="#B5F7D3" />`